# HDMI Audio stops when turn off monitor

Tags: audio, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a new `MSI GX70` and when I listen to music on it I like to hook up the `HDMI` to my sound system and turn off the monitor but unlike all my previous machines when I press the display off button the `HDMI` sound quits(not the built in speakers though if I am using them)
I am really curious if there is a way to fix this and I cant seem to figure it out by myself.

```
MSI GX70
Windows 8
APU A10 5750m
Radeon HD 8650G + 8970m
```